# I am trying to re-start an existing loop to iterate through it again with a new comparison value

Tags: visual-workflow, loop

Problem- Looping through a collection of values looking for a matching value to a previously assigned variable. It is possible a match does not exist.
The variable value is now changed and I need to restart the loop again to check for the new value.

What I have tried:

1. Within the loop, I updated the assigned variable value to a new value, connecting to the loop, results in End Loop.
2. Within the loop, I updated the assigned variable value to a new value, connecting to to original get records that creates the collection the loop runs through, results in End Loop.

Is there a way to "reset" the loop?

Comment: Have you considered using [collection filtering](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_filter.htm&type=5)?

Comment: @PhilW Thank you for your response. I am using a collection filter to determine which records to run the flow on. 

I have figured this out. I already had a counter in my loop counting through the iterations. I have now added an assignment to reset that counter to "0" and then followed it with a decision on whether or not to restart the flow based on the counter being visited. It seems to be working now. Still testing all scenarios.

Comment: Feel free to post a self-answer here to help others in future.

Comment: Adding the reset of the loop counter allowed me to restart the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the reset of the loop counter allowed me to restart the loop.